# Next.js 13 webpack "URLPattern is not a constructor"

Tags: webpack, next.js, url-pattern

inside app directory, `page.tsx`:

```
import { URLPattern } from "next/server";
const url = new URLPattern();
```

this is in a typescript file and typescript does not complain. When I hover over `URLPattern`:

```
(alias) class URLPattern
import URLPattern
```

Everything seems fine, but when I visit the page, I get this error on terminal:

```
error - TypeError: next_server__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.URLPattern is not a constructor
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/page.tsx:30:14)
    at (sc_server)/./app/page.tsx (/home/Documents/projects/next.js/youtube-next13-static-blog/.next/server/app/page.js:678:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (/home/Documents/projects/next.js/youtube-next13-static-blog/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async collectGenerateParams (/home/Documents/projects/next.js/youtube-next13-static-blog/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:713:17) {
  type: 'TypeError',
  page: '/'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install [urlpattern-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urlpattern-polyfill)

In the `app` directory

```
if (!globalThis.URLPattern) {
  await import("urlpattern-polyfill");
}
```

You do not need to import anything else

Comment: This is weird, why would we have to do this when I just started new nextjs app and ther eis no mention about it?